# Google script creates two spreadsheets instead of one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day!
My script processing form submission on spreadsheet side.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
      var obj, scriptProperties, counter;
      var prop = 'submissions';
      obj = raw_answer_to_raw_obj(e.values);//this function pack answer into object
      scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 
      counter = scriptProperties.getProperty(prop);
      if (counter==null) counter = 0;
      counter++;
      scriptProperties.setProperty(prop, counter);
      new_answer_processing(obj);
    }
```

with calls at the end main processing function wich I can test emulating the obj.
new_answer_processing() function calls function create_ss_in_folder only once:

```
function create_ss_in_folder(folder_name, name, root) {
      var ss, id, file, folder;
      Logger.log('creating spreadsheet...');
      ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
      id = ss.getId();
      Logger.log('ss id: ' + id);
      file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      var folder = get_folder_by_name(folder_name, root);
      folder.addFile(file);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
      return ss;
    }
```

Singleton of call proved by logfile and call counter submissions (you can watch video http://youtu.be/DTawqYPa44A)
but in fact it's make two spreadsheets.
This error occurs not each time when the form submits and never if I emulate submission by script.
Is it a reason for issue or I miss something?

Comment: As I'm aware, form submissions do have a duplicate problem, but only remember of mailApp ones. Share the `raw_answer_to_raw_obj` just to be sure. Also check [Issue 4752](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4752).

Comment: Thanks for answer. It looks like an google issue.It is a pitty that this has been going on for more than two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Google reports that issue fixed
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4752